# React Component Not Working with Cannonicals and Alternates

Tags: reactjs

I eventaully tried mutliple times with developers to solve the issue of cannonicals corrections with alternate for othe language pages in https://invisibletext.net any expert can visit i am also sharing the code, even i taken help from chatgpt but still we are unable to solve it ... May be someone expert could solve it becuase we are trying for 2 months now!!!! fed up

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Canonicalization = (allow) => {
  const location = useLocation(a.URL);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Example: Get the current language from the URL
    const currentLanguage = location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    const canonicalUrl = canonicalUrls[currentLanguage] || canonicalUrls.en;

    // Example: Add the canonical link tag to the document head
    const linkElement = document.createElement('link');
    linkElement.rel = 'canonical';
    linkElement.href = canonicalUrl;
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement);

    // Clean up the link tag when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(linkElement);
    };
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return null;
};

export default Canonicalization;
```

Cannonical corrections and issues

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Please [edit] it to clearly state the problem, what you expect to happen vs what actually happens and any error messages your code produces

Comment: First issue I can see is that neither `a` nor `canonicalUrls` is defined

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors with variable definitions when I put this code into my sandbox. Also, you don't need to pass params to the window location

**If you're looking to update the canonical you can do something like this:**

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Canonicalization = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Example: Get the current language from the URL
    const currentLanguage = location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    // Define your canonical URLs for different languages
    const canonicalUrls = {
      en: 'https://invisibletext.net/en',  // Replace with your actual URLs
      // Add more languages as needed
    };

    const canonicalUrl = canonicalUrls[currentLanguage] || canonicalUrls.en;

    // Example: Add the canonical link tag to the document head
    const linkElement = document.createElement('link');
    linkElement.rel = 'canonical';
    linkElement.href = canonicalUrl;
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement);

    // Clean up the link tag when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(linkElement);
    };
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return null;
};

export default Canonicalization;
```

### Or use React Helmet (recommended)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Canonicalization = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Example: Get the current language from the URL
  const currentLanguage = location.pathname.split('/')[1];

  // Define your canonical URLs for different languages
  const canonicalUrls = {
    en: 'https://invisibletext.net/en',  // Replace with your actual URLs
    // Add more languages as needed
  };

  // State to manage the dynamic canonical URL
  const [canonicalUrl, setCanonicalUrl] = useState(canonicalUrls[currentLanguage] || canonicalUrls.en);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update canonical URL when the language changes
    setCanonicalUrl(canonicalUrls[currentLanguage] || canonicalUrls.en);
  }, [currentLanguage]);

  return (
    <Helmet>
      <link rel="canonical" href={canonicalUrl} />
    </Helmet>
  );
};

export default Canonicalization;
```

Comment: I'd move the constant parts out of the component personally. No need to redefine them every time it renders.